# dc.js use filter from other dataset

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I run into a problem when I have multiple datasets in crossfilter.
I create one crossfilter for each dataset.
I want to filter my data in the pie chart when I select the Year dimension in the bubble chart. They are from different datasets, but they all have Year column.

Bubble chart:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var yearDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.FiscalYear; });
var yearlyPerformanceGroup = yearDimension.group().reduceSum(return d.Value);
```

Pie chart

```
var ndxobi = crossfilter(obligation);
var yearDimension = ndxobi.dimension(function (d) { return d.FiscalYear; });
var obligationDimension = ndxobi.dimension(function (d) { return d.Type; });
var valueObligationSumGroup = obligationDimension.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.Value; });
```

Could some one tell me how to select the year in bubble chart and then pass it to the pie chart?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is going to work better if they use a common crossfilter, but you can probably get something working just by listening to the `filtered` event on the bubble chart and filtering the pie chart when it fires:

```
bubbleChart.on('filtered', function(chart) {
    pieChart.filter(null)
        .filter([chart.filters()])
        .redrawGroup();
});
```

This removes the old filter on the pie chart, applies the new one, and then causes all the charts in the pie chart's crossfilter to redraw.

Docs:

- [`filtered` event](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#basemixinon--basemixin)
- [`chart.filter()`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.baseMixin+filter)

Comment: Thank you Gordon. But my problem is that in the pie chart, my dimension is not Year. However, it is called obligationDimension. The pie chart shows the ratio of two kinds of obligation. I want to select year in Bubble chart and then change the ratio in Piechart based on the year I selected. I think your method will filter on yearDimension of piechart, but I group by the value of piechart based on obligationDimension. Could you tell me how to solve that?

Comment: Okay, that's not what you showed in your code. But I think all you need to do is create another dimension on the pie's crossfilter which is by year, and filter that instead. If this is still not what you mean, please edit your question.

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I use the year dimension in the obligation crossfilter to create a bar chart and filter on the bar chart. Then the pie chart automatically filtered. But it can only filter once. If  I want to select the second year or the third year, it can not filter anymore. For example, I select 2011 year first, if I want to see the three years result of 2009, 2010 and 2011, the graph can not filter for three years. It remains the result of 2011.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the code for the multiple select case. This is more general purpose.